# Different parent child namespace prefix expected

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have two xsds from which i have generated jaxb pojos using xjc. And i have generated XMLs using jaxb marshaller with jaxb-impl-2.2.6
For this I have overriden NamespacePrefixMapper as MyNamespacePrefixMapper

Parent.xsd

```
 <xs:schema targetNamespace="parent" 
       elementFormDefault="qualified" 
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:Env="Parent" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:child="urn:xsd:child">
<xs:import namespace="urn:xsd:child" schemaLocation="child.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="parent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child" type="child:child1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

child.xsd

```
  <xs:schema xmlns="urn:xsd:child" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:xsd:child">
<xs:element name="child" type="child1"/>
<xs:complexType name="child1">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Id" type="Max20Text"/>    
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="Max20Text">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

XmlMarshallingTest.java

```
 import javax.xml.bind.*;
 import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import parent.Parent;
 import xsd.child.Child1;
  public class XmlMarshallingTest {


  @Test
   public void testXmlMarshalling() throws  JAXBException, XMLStreamException{
    Parent envelope = new Parent();
    Child1 businessApplicationHeaderV01 = new Child1();
    businessApplicationHeaderV01.setId("ABC123");
    envelope.setChild(businessApplicationHeaderV01);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(envelope.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", new MyNamespacePrefixMapper());
    marshaller.marshal(envelope, System.out);
    }
}
```

MyNamespacePrefixMapper.java

```
    import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;
    import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;

    public class MyNamespacePrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper {
@Override
public String getPreferredPrefix(String namespaceUri, String suggestion, boolean arg2) {
    if("Parent".equals(namespaceUri)) {
        return "parentPrefix";
    } else if("urn:xsd:child".equals(namespaceUri)) {
        return "childPrefix";
    }
    return "defaultPrefix";
}
  }
```

the generated xml is like

```
 <parentPrefix:parent xmlns:childPrefix="urn:xsd:child" xmlns:parentPrefix="parent">
   <parentPrefix:child>
    <childPrefix:Id>ABC123</childPrefix:Id>
   </parentPrefix:child>
 </parentPrefix:parent>
```

Here, my problem is , I expect the xml to be look like following

```
 <parentPrefix:parent xmlns:childPrefix="urn:xsd:child" xmlns:parentPrefix="parent">
  <childPrefix:child>
    <childPrefix:Id>ABC123</childPrefix:Id>
  </childPrefix:child>
 </parentPrefix:parent>
```

I expect the prefix of child tag to be "**childPrefix**" but it shows "**parentPrefix**"
The parent tag is well generated with prefix "**parentPrefix**"

**Environment  Description**

Maven 3.0.4

Java version: 1.7.0_04

OS : windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema defines the `parent` element as having a child element named `child` in the parent schema's own targetNamespace, whose *type* happens to come from the child namespace.  If you want the parent to use the `child` element that is defined in the child schema (and thus in the `urn:xsd:child` namespace) then instead of

```
<xs:element name="child" type="child:child1"/>
```

you need

```
<xs:element ref="child:child"/>
```